# having two views at the same time on the screen while one is required(iphone)

Tags: iphone, view, screen

I have two views ,when Im clicking on a button to bring the first view the tap of the other view is still at the bottom of the page of the firs view.

but When I click on that tap to bring me the second view,it brings it behind the first view!How can I fix this?

THANKS

Comment: Please post some code and further clarify your question. It's impossible to currently understand what your question even is.

Answer (score 0):

you can bring it at front ,like this

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:secondView];
```